# Page Breaks in RDLC Report?

Tags: rdlc

I have an RDLC report that I'm having problems with page breaks. The report has a group that has a number of records that do not fit on one page. This report renders fine in Normal Mode, but when I switch to Print Mode, "extra" page breaks that were not there before appear. This is causing the report to print on more pages than necessary. I do not have the group set to keep on one page, and I have been playing with the values for Height and InteractiveHeight, but nothing seems to work.

Is there any way to resolve this problem? I need this report to print out properly, and these mysterious page breaks are causing this problem. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you check your margin settings on the report properties dialogue. I think the default is 1 inch on all sides. That could be throwing off the printing.

Answer (score 3):

Just set ur page size property as ==8.5in, 3.625in, and then view your report

Comment: This actually worked to fix a related issue for me.  Adding page breaks caused my ReportViewer to err.  Changing the report to 8.5 X 10in from 8.5 X 11in fixed the issue.

Comment: This was also my problem, although slightly different dimensions

Answer (score 3):

If you have just converted to 2010, this will fix your problem (see last entry)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/9d493130-6683-4ec8-bbe0-9524df8859c5

> Look at the bottom of the ReportViewer Designer area and you should
>   see "Row Groups".  My Report's Table's name is "Table_LineItems" and I
>   see "Table_LineItems_Details_Group".  I select that and in my Property
>   window I set "Keep Together" to false.  Then it prints correctly.  I
>   can't guarantee that this will work for you, but I suggest playing
>   with whatever you see down there.   You can also (on the far right)
>   click an unlabeled drop down and select advanced mode and
>   indiscriminately set more of the "Static" items to KeepTogether =
>   false.

Answer (score 2):

Select table,right click,  go to properties,add NEW group right after any group you have ( in that case I call 'PreviousGroupName"), expression should be  **=(RowNumber("PreviousGroupName") - 1) \27+ 1**, check **Page break at end**. It will fit 27 rows in the web and when export into .PDF you should see the same 27 rows. You can change 27 to any number you need to fit your page,

Then you can change Viewer HEIGHT (in .aspx) to any size,to avoid Scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

I set the option `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace = True` in the Report Properties and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking the width of the elements. You have to make sure that they are within the margins of the print layout, or you'll get extra pages. Make sure your margins aren't really wide (I think they are by default).

Answer (score 0):

I made the body size (height width) of the report smaller than the page width and page height on report properties.

Finally, the blank pages disappeared.